# Как правильно хранить (например) список товаров заказа (mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть предположение хранить что то в таком духе:

```
Orders(order_id, user_id, unixTime) 
Ordered(order_id, product_id, amount)
```

Но возникает 1 проблема. После создания записи в таблице `Orders` нам нужно будет получить `order_id`. Это можно сделать с помощью функции `mysql_insert_id()`, которая возвращает `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Что, если одновременно будет 2 заказа, т.е. как то так:

```
Создание записи в Orders
Создание записи в Orders
Вызов mysql_insert_id()
Вызов mysql_insert_id()
```

Это надо обрамлять каким то аналогом критической секцией? Или мой подход к хранению заказанных товаров некорректен? (т.к. `race condition` тут всё портит)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. в Ordered обязательно добавить цену
2. ничего "обрамялть" не нужно. Для каждого соединения возвращается свое значение.

Comment: Транзакции видно не для нас придумали? А по первому надо сначала узнать как таблицы соотносятся. Если 1-к-1, то можно и внести, если многие-к-1, то смысл в этом?

Comment: Спасибо за первый пункт - добавлю. 
Спасибо и за второй, не знал на счет этой особенности.